# getQty() giving fatal error in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, collection, quantity, query

I am trying to get the collection based on product and quote Id

```
    $quotecollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id);

   $quotecollectionaArr =  $quotecollection->getData();
    echo $quotecollection->getQty();
```

Gave me the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::getQty() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs.... Please help.

Comment: have you got array inside $quotecollectionaArr?

Comment: ye i am able to print it  @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: try with $quotecollectionaArr['qty'] and check

Comment: this give blank

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? you need the qty of what?

Comment: I have the product id and quote id,Now need to get the qty of the quote

Comment: @Melvin check my answer I think it solve your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
$quotecollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id);

//$quotecollectionaArr =  $quotecollection->getData();
foreach($quotecollection as $quote){
   echo $quote->getQty()
}
```

**2ndWay**

```
$quotecollection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$product_id)->getFirstItem();
  //getFirstItem will do the trick  
  echo $quotecollection->getQty();
```

Comment: there is no other way without using forech ?

Comment: yes there is a way give me 5 minute I will update

Comment: @Melvin please check updated code

Answer (score 0):

First, your `$quotecollection` contains a collection of quote items. So calling `getData` on it will not let you retrieve the qty for each item.

To do so, I suggest you do the following:

```
$qtysFromCollection = $quotecollection->getColumnValues('qty');
```

You will get an array that will contain the quantity for each quote item in your collection.

This `getColumnValues` will do the loop and generate the array for you, you can find its code under the `Varien_Data_Collection` class:

```
/**
 * Retrieve field values from all items
 *
 * @param   string $colName
 * @return  array
 */
public function getColumnValues($colName)
{
    $this->load();

    $col = array();
    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $col[] = $item->getData($colName);
    }
    return $col;
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnValues() on a non-object

Comment: @Melvin hmmmm I had a typo see my updated answer